# Cannot uninstall myspell-he

Tags: apt, dpkg

I tried to install a Hebrew spell checker for LibreOffice. I downloaded a package named `myspell-he_1.1-1_all.deb` and tried to install it through the software center. Installation failed and I can neither complete installation nor remove it. Since then, whenever I run Update Manager I get an error message:

```
The package system is broken.
```

In details:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
dictionaries-common:
```

When I try to run the Software center I get a pop-up window:

```
Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired.
```

A Repair option is suggested. If I click it the following nessage appears:

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of myspell-he:
 dictionaries-common (1.12.1ubuntu2) breaks myspell-he (<= 1.1-1) and is installed.
  Version of myspell-he to be configured is 1.1-1.
dpkg: error processing myspell-he (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 myspell-he
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of myspell-he:
 dictionaries-common (1.12.1ubuntu2) breaks myspell-he (<= 1.1-1) and is installed.
  Version of myspell-he to be configured is 1.1-1.
dpkg: error processing myspell-he (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

How can I clear this mess?

Comment: There is no need to download packages one by one, use the repositories next time. To remove myspell-he try the following: `sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq -P myspell-he`. Hope that works.

Comment: Glad it did, I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal window, please run the following:

```
sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq -P myspell-he
```

That should force the removal of the `myspell-he` package.